# Autocomlete item scroll Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

This is my code to  implement autocomplete in android and its click event.

```
AutoCompleteTextView StreetDataNew = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.Street)
 ...........................
 .........................

StreetDataNew 
        .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "unchecked" })
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                    View arg1, int index, long id) {


            }
        });
```

Please tell me how to catch the autocomplete item is scrolled or not ?

Comment: what you mean by scrolled or not ?

Comment: means just scroll through the autocomplete list items

Comment: scroll through means choosing another item ??

Comment: @Amrola yes scrool up/down  to c the next item

Comment: working on it , give me 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like the following to know if the selected item is above your last selection one or below :

1st - create a variable to store the value of the last selected :

```
private int lastIndex ;
```

2nd - set OnItemClickListener on your AutoCompletetextView like the following :

```
autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

3rd - implement your onItemClick like the following :

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        if(lastIndex==position){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "same positon ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else if (position<lastIndex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "scroll up",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if (position>lastIndex){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "scroll down ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        lastIndex=position;


    }
```

and please give me some feedback

Hope that helps .